# Why Final variables in scala are allowed to change values

Tags: scala

Why Final variables in Scala are allowed to change values. As per my understanding once declared final, they shouldn't be allowed to change.

```
class foo()
{
  final var name = "abc"
  name = "xyz" // why this is allowed
}
```

Comment: I decompiled the code above using "JAD decompiler" and found that Getter and Setter for name are final but name in the decompiled code is stated as 
"private String name" and not as "private final String name". I guess that's why final var name in above code is allowed to change.

Comment: "As per my understanding once declared final, they shouldn't be allowed to change." – What makes you think that `final` has anything whatsoever to do with mutability? Is there anything in the Scala Language Specification that makes you think so? It might be a good idea to file a bug against the SLS if that is the case, misleading wording is not a good thing in a specification!

Comment: I got stumbled over intertwined concepts while learning Scala and categorically stated my understanding only to let fellow mates get clear idea on my grip, so that one can frame the answer based on my knowledge(may be half baked). I don't think i have gone misleading in any way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`final` definition per the [Scala Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#final) (emphasis mine):

### 5.2.6 final

> The final modifier applies to class member definitions and to class definitions. 
>   A final class member definition **may not be overridden in subclasses**. A
>   final class **may not be inherited by a template**. final is redundant for
>   object definitions. Members of final classes or objects are implicitly
>   also final, so the final modifier is generally redundant for them,
>   too. Note, however, **that constant value definitions do require an
>   explicit final modifier**, even if they are defined in a final class or
>   object. final may not be applied to incomplete members, and it may not
>   be combined in one modifier list with sealed.

Since a `val` definition in Scala already means that the reference to it is immutable (unlike Java), you don't have to explicitly specify that when defining it. If you want the value to be inlined as a constant in the byte code, you can specify add the `final` modifier.

As per `var`, final here only means *"may not be overridden in subclasses"*, but says nothing about the *immutability* of the variable:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Foo {
  final var name = "abc"
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  override var name = "yuval"
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:16: error: overriding variable name in class Foo of type String;
 variable name cannot override final member
             override var name = "yuval"
```

Answer (score 15):

The `final` keyword does not bear the same meaning it does in Java.

In Java it can both mean that a class or method cannot be extended or overridden and that a reference is immutable.

In Scala `final` only bears the first meaning, while to have an immutable reference you ought to use the `val` keyword.

```
class Foo {
  val name: String = "abc"
  // name = "xyz" // would be a compilation error

  final var surname: String = "def"
  surname = "uvw" // ok
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  override val name: String = "xyz"
  override var surname: String = "rst" // compilation error
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Regarding `final`, it comes into picture whether you extend or override the class/variable or not.

### Without final you can override in your child class

```
class Fruit {
  val color = "Green"
}

class AmericanFruit extends Fruit {
  override val color = "Red"
}
```

### With final, you can not override variable to your child class.

[image: final]

Also, can not inherit the `final` class,

[image: final class]

Use `val` for immutable data. (`val` for immutable value)

example

```
scala> val immutableName = "you can not change me"
immutableName: String = you can not change me

scala> immutableName = "change me"
<console>:12: error: reassignment to val
       immutableName = "change me"
            ^
```

And for mutable, you use `var` (`var` for variable)

```
scala> var mutableName = "you can change me"
mutableName: String = you can change me

scala> mutableName = "i am changed"
mutableName: String = i am changed
```

Comment: Thanks for response Sir. I know that val is immutable and var is mutable but only for sake of understanding i wish to know why var when declared as final is allowed to change. In java we can't change final variables but why this is allowed in SCala

Comment: final comes into pictue whether you can override the variable or not. with `final` you can not override.